# virtualbox NAT configuration does not work as expected

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

I set up 2 VMs in virtual box on a centos machines but it looks like NAT configuration does not work as expected. As a foreword I would like to remind what's in the virtualbox manual regarding NAT configuration (source: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat):

> [...]it does not require any configuration on the host network and
> guest system. For this reason, it is the default networking mode in
> Oracle VM VirtualBox.
>
> [...]The virtual machine receives its network address and
> configuration on the private network from a DHCP server integrated
> into Oracle VM VirtualBox
>
> [...]the first card is connected to the private network 10.0.2.0, the
> second card to the network 10.0.3.0 and so on.

my configuration:

#--HOST--#

```
cat /etc/os-release                                                                                                                                                                           
NAME="CentOS Stream"                                                                                                                                                                          
VERSION="8"                                                                                                                                                                                   
ID="centos"                                                                                                                                                                                   
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"                                                                                                                                                                         
VERSION_ID="8"                                                                                                                                                                                
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"                                                                                                                                                                    
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Stream 8"                                                                                                                                                                 
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"                                                                                                                                                                             
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"                                                                                                                                                             
HOME_URL="https://centos.org/"                                                                                                                                                                
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"                                                                                                                                                 
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"                                                                                                                                           
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="CentOS Stream" 
                                                                                                                                                                             
 uname -a                                                                                                                                                                                     
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.0-536.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 18 15:15:29 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

virtualbox:
Version 7.0.14 r161095 (Qt5.15.3)

No Extension Pack installed.
No Guest Addition installed.

```
free -h                                                                                                                                                                                       
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available                                                                                                               
Mem:           11Gi       3.4Gi       5.9Gi       818Mi       2.2Gi       7.0Gi                                                                                                               
Swap:         5.8Gi

grep 'processor\|model name' /proc/cpuinfo                                                                                                                                                    
processor       : 0                                                                                                                                                                           
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz                                                                                                                                    
processor       : 1                                                                                                                                                                           
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz                                                                                                                                    
processor       : 2                                                                                                                                                                           
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz                                                                                                                                    
processor       : 3                                                                                                                                                                           
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz 

cat /var/log/vbox-setup.log*                                                                                                                                                                  
Building the net filter module.                                                                                                                                                               
Building the net adapter module.                                                                                                                                                              
Building the main VirtualBox module.                                                                                                                                                          
Building the main VirtualBox module.                                                                                                                                                          
Building the main VirtualBox module.

cat ./Xorg.*.log | grep -i box                                                                                                                                                                
no output
```

#--GUEST--#

base memory: 1024 MB

1 cpu

In the vm logs, it looks like there are no NAT related errors.

I want to configure NAT.
In File -> Tools -> Network Manager -> NAT Networks:
NatNetwork 10.0.2.0/24, DHCP enabled (yes I know 'Nat networks' is no 'NAT' in vbox glossary, but there is no NAT tab).
Networking settings on the VM:
Attached to: NAT
Cable Connected is checked

```
ip -br -c addr                                                                                                                                                                                
lo    UNKNOWN  127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128                                                                                                                                                            
enp0s3      UP                                                                                                                                                                                
enp0s8      DOWN                                                                                                                                                                              
virbr0      DOWN     192.168.122.1/24                                                                                                                                                         
virbr0-nic  DOWN
```

As you can see network 10.0.2.0/24 does not show any ip up. What did I miss?

thanx folks!

Comment: Was the `ip addr` output from host or guest?

Comment: @ul686_grawity: I put a summary using `ip -br -c addr`; only the loopback and virbr0 interfaces have got an ip attached. I still can copy by hand (because there is no add-ons for the moment,  I cannot copy & paste) the `ip addr` would not give more layer 3 related infos.

Comment: I didn't ask for that, I asked whether the output came from the host OS or from a VM guest OS.

Comment: Install Guest Extensions and restart the guest. Then check NAT

Comment: from the VM. I will install Guest Extensions and will try again.

Comment: 'VBoxGuestAdditions' has been installed and is working smoothly.
'Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.14.vbox-extpack' has also been installed. 
In Tools -> NetworkManager -> NAT Network -> I still have NatNetwork - 10.0.2.0/24 (with DHCP enabled)
but command `ip -br -c addr` does still not show  any interface attached to this network.